# How to pass a instance of XmlDocument to argumentTransformList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

I want to pass a XmlDocument to a Xml asp control
something like that :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
myXmlControl.TransformArgumentList.AddParam("xml_document_content",xmlDoc.innerXML);
```

In order to use the parameter in xslt like a node set.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please give us some idea of what this control does. Is it server-side or client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searches I finally use :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
object param = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("/");
myXmlControl.TransformArgumentList.AddParam("xml_document_content",param );
```